# Centering images in a container with Vuetify

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

The following Vuetify example

```js
<template>
  <v-sheet
    class="d-flex align-end justify-center pa-5"
    width="1600"
    height="400"
  >
    <v-img v-for="img in images" :key="img.id" class="ma-1" :src="img.data" />
  </v-sheet>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

const images = ref([
  { id: 0, data: "src/assets/1.png" },
  { id: 1, data: "src/assets/2.png" },
  { id: 2, data: "src/assets/3.png" },
]);
</script>
```

[produces this output](https://i.imgur.com/Qn8uAPe.png).

[The problem with it is the images are not contained to only their true size](https://i.imgur.com/CnsQRqM.png) and so when there is no enough to fill the full width they are equally spaced.

I want the images to fill up as much space as they can (so to use all the available height or width as appropriate), [but to be center justified when they do not fill the full width](https://i.imgur.com/bLLVToi.png)
.

I can achieve this behaviour by passing a `max-width` prop to the `v-img`, but the value has to be carefully chosen and so it will not work with a variable v-sheet size and a variable array of images (although all of the same size). I have tried implementing some script for calculating the necessary `max-width` value, but it feels very hacky and I'm sure there must be a much better way to do it.

Any help appreciated!